# How can I keep row selections in QItemSelectionModel when columns are sorted?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using QItemSelectionModel with QTableView to allow the users to select rows. The problem is that when the user then clicks on a column header to sort the rows, the selection disappears and all the sorted data is displayed. How can I keep the selection, and just sort that, rather than having all the rows appear?

Thanks!
--Erin

Comment: If the data is updated the selection disappears of course. To keep the selection after the data on the list is rearrenged I guess you should use some kind of id code for each row. So you can determinate which row was selected and then select it again after the sort.

Comment: @dex19dt Would putting the indexes of the selected rows into an array and then re-hiding the superfluous rows after the sort be the best way to do this? How can I catch the sort through QTableView?

Comment: Work with the widget's indexes (the ones returned by currentRow() or currentItem()) isn't a good idea because they change everytime the data is updated or new lines are inserted. Like I said, You should insert some id unique code for control (maybe in a hidden widget?) so you can have an exclusive code for every row at the moment they are displayed. I remember I did something like that in an early project. It's hard to guess when I don't know actually what kind of program you're working on, but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I ended up solving this problem:

- When row selections are made, put the unique IDs of each hidden row into a list, then hide all hidden rows
- Use self.connect(self.myHorizontalHeader, SIGNAL("sectionClicked(int)"), self.keepSelectionValues) to catch the
  event when a user clicks on a column header to sort the rows
- In self.keepSelectionValue, go through each row and if the unique ID is in the hidden row list, hide the row

This effectively sorts and displays the non-hidden rows without displaying all the rows of the entire table.